# How do I cut substrings in these strings in powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, scripting

everyone. I'm a rookie at Powershell and I don't know much about the values in a particular column.

```
JOBID    STATUS       STORAGE POLICY        APPTYPE          BACKUPSET           SUBCLIENT                              INSTANCE                CLIENT                       

-----    ------       --------------        -------          ---------           ---------                              --------                ------                       

647      Completed    SP_Dedupe Files       File System      defaultBackupSet    ClienteDDB                             <default>               WIN-U0O9K2LMAF1              

641      Completed    SP_Dedupe Files       File System      defaultBackupSet    DDBBackup                              <default>               WIN-U0O9K2LMAF1
```

I filter the lines with a Select-String by jobid for example but I need the value of subclient column in particular. 
As it is not a cmdlet I can't split by properties, so how do I do it with a regular expression?and which one?

Comment: is this your source text file? if not show a relevant portion of source file

Comment: like this or you mean a picture?

Comment: I’ve seen something like this with the Avamar backup server. Are you outputting this with a command from the backup console? If so, I’d try to see if there is an xml export command of this information that Powershell can easily read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution will be to output the data in a format that is more PowerShell ready. An XML or CSV format would be ideal as PowerShell can convert those formats into objects.

You can use a `-match` and `-split` combination here assuming your data is in `file.txt`:

```
$jobid = 641
$values = (Get-Content file.txt) -match "^$jobid\s+" -split '\s{2,}'
$values[5] # SUBCLIENT value
$values[7] # CLIENT value
```

Since your text file will invariably have more than one line of text, you can read the file with [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) and match against your `jobid` number. The `-match` [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) will return only the line that matches the `jobid`. It behaves this way because `Get-Content` without the `-Raw` switch reads each line into an array index.

The match regex string `"^$jobid\s+"` is enclosed in double quotes so that the variable `$jobid` expands. Single quotes will prevent expansion and use the verbatim string. `^` matches the start of the string. `\s+` matches one or more consecutive spaces.

[-split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) uses regex matching and then splits the single string into an array based on that match. `\s{2,}` matches two or more consecutive spaces. The split array is stored in `$values`. Now, you can reference whichever column number (starting with 0) using syntax `$value[number]`.

Note that this solution still has potential issues if any of your columns are only one space apart. It will be difficult to code around that situation. You'd have to include conditions where you explicitly list potential values for each column in your code. The alternative is to stop using spaces in your values or use values that clearly indicate when a new column is starting.

---

[AVshalom's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150503/11025476) solution points you in a very good direction if reading raw strings. Working with a CSV is superior to text matching in this case. However, the solution has flaws and misaligns your data. The flaws are easily correctable though. `\s{2,}` should be used in favor of `\s+` (one or more consecutive spaces) because values that contain spaces will also be replaced. You can see this behavior since the output has more columns than the original file. We can take this solution further using conditional logic.

```
# If values have commas, you will need a different delimiter
$jobid = 641
$csv = (Get-Content file.txt) -replace '\s{2,}',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
$csv | Where JOBID -eq $jobid | Select-Object -Expand SUBCLIENT
```

[Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/removing-objects-from-the-pipeline--where-object-?view=powershell-7) or [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/removing-objects-from-the-pipeline--where-object-?view=powershell-7) uses a condition (checking JOBID here) used to retrieve the correct line. Then you can pipe to [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) or [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) to retrieve the `SUBCLIENT` value. Using `-Expand` only prints the value of the property. Leaving off `-Expand` will print an object containing the `SUBCLIENT` property.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution... Using `ConvertFrom-Csv`

```
$text = @"
JOBID    STATUS       STORAGE POLICY        APPTYPE          BACKUPSET           SUBCLIENT                              INSTANCE                CLIENT                       

-----    ------       --------------        -------          ---------           ---------                              --------                ------                       

647      Completed    SP_Dedupe Files       File System      defaultBackupSet    ClienteDDB                             <default>               WIN-U0O9K2LMAF1              

641      Completed    SP_Dedupe Files       File System      defaultBackupSet    DDBBackup                              <default>               WIN-U0O9K2LMAF1 
"@ -split '\n' | ? {$_ -notmatch '---|^\s+'}

$csv = $text | % {$_ -replace '\s+',','} | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Will results this:

```
JOBID STATUS    STORAGE   POLICY APPTYPE BACKUPSET SUBCLIENT        INSTANCE   CLIENT   
----- ------    -------   ------ ------- --------- ---------        --------   ------   
647   Completed SP_Dedupe Files  File    System    defaultBackupSet ClienteDDB <default>
641   Completed SP_Dedupe Files  File    System    defaultBackupSet DDBBackup  <default>

$csv[0].JOBID
647
```

Comment: You should use `\s{2,}` rather than `\s+`. Either way there is potential for things to not be quite right.

Comment: You guys are geniuses. Thank you so much.